# What is the best way in Python to execute a script while maintaining namespace and passing args

Tags: python, namespaces, exec, subprocess

I am looking for a way to execute another python script within my code.

I need to maintain access to the variables of the calling script as well as pass the new script arguments.

From what I've looked at so far it seems:
exec() can maintain the namespace, but can't receive arguments(or at least in an easy way) 
subprocess() can pass arguments, but can't maintain the namespace because it creates a new process.

Is there a workaround for either of these functions? Possibly setting the argv variable then passing the env to exec() or somehow maintaining the namespace for subprocess()

Comment: I ended up making a second args variable, ARGS.  Then, I passed locals() to exec().  This wasn't perfect, but matched a previously implement system I was working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change `sys.argv` and pass a namespace in to `exec`

```
import sys
script_path = "otherscript.py"
old_argv, sys.argv = sys.argv,[script_path, "arg1", "arg2"]
namespace = dict(globals())
if globals() is not locals():
    namespace.update(locals())
with open(script_path, 'r') as infile:
    exec(compile(infile.read(), script_path, 'exec'), namespace)
sys.argv = old_argv
```

Whether using `exec` is a good idea is another story, as always, but that's how you'd do it. Depending on your exact situation you might change the way you handle globals and locals. (Actually, it would be much better to explicitly place only the values you need into `namespace`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `imp`. Example:

```
import imp

module_name = imp.load_source('module_name', '/path/to/module_name.py')
```

You can now use the module you imported. As long as the script is protected by a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, you should be fine.